# Upload Multiple images to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I relatively new to PHP. I need to upload multiple images to the database with one button tap. this is the code. I understand that I have to add a foreach loop to go through each image individually(insert the images individually) but I can't seem to find the right place to insert the for each loop. Any answers would be very much appreciated.

```
<?php

    error_reporting( ~E_NOTICE ); // avoid notice

    require_once 'dbconfig.php';

    if(isset($_POST['btnsave']))
    {
        $carname = $_POST['car_name'];// car name
        $carmodel = $_POST['car_model'];// car model
        $caramount = $_POST['car_amount'];// car amount

        $imgFile = $_FILES['car_image']['name'];
        $tmp_dir = $_FILES['car_image']['tmp_name'];
        $imgSize = $_FILES['car_image']['size'];


        if(empty($carname)){
            $errMSG = "Please Enter Name of the Car.";
        }
        else if(empty($carmodel)){
            $errMSG = "Please Enter Model Number of the car.";
        }
        else if(empty($caramount)){
            $errMSG = "Please Enter the cost of the car.";
        }
        else if(empty($imgFile)){
            $errMSG = "Please Select Image File.";
        }
        else
        {

            $upload_dir = 'user_images/'; // upload directory

            $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // get image extension

            // valid image extensions
            $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'); // valid extensions

            // rename uploading image
            $carpic = rand(1000,1000000).".".$imgExt;

            // allow valid image file formats
            if(in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions)){            
                // Check file size '5MB'
                if($imgSize < 5000000)                {
                    move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir,$upload_dir.$carpic);
                }
                else{
                    $errMSG = "Sorry, your file is too large.";
                }
            }
            else{
                $errMSG = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";        
            }
        }


        // if no error occured, continue ....
        if(!isset($errMSG))
        {
            $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl_cars(carName,carModel,carAmount,carPic) VALUES(:cname, :cmodel, :camount, :cpic)');
            $stmt->bindParam(':cname',$carname);
            $stmt->bindParam(':cmodel',$carmodel);
            $stmt->bindParam(':camount',$caramount);
            $stmt->bindParam(':cpic',$carpic);
            if($stmt->execute())
            {
                $successMSG = "new record succesfully inserted ...";
                header("refresh:5;car_display.php"); // redirects image view page after 5 seconds.
            }
            else
            {
                $errMSG = "error while inserting....";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

I know I need to add a simple for each loop, execution is failing me.
Somebody Save Me

This is the HTML bit that uploads

```
 <tr>
        <td><label class="control-label">Car Img.</label></td>
        <td><input class="input-group" type="file" name="car_image" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" /></td>
```

Comment: You have the answer,  a loop to iterate on each and all images,  check it's size, change it's name,  whatever operation you intend to perform,  and then insert in the DB.  Indeed you can create an array of images and loop the images.

Comment: Yes i know, i just can't seem to execute it properly. Remember that i'm extremely new to php.

Comment: Nobody's gonna save you... `$_FILES` looks different when there's multiple files. How's your `<input type="file">` in your `<form>` *(could be nice to see your HTML)* ? Tried a `print_r($_FILES)` when the form is submitted ? I bet you could find yourself the answer by trying this and searching a bit instead of asking for "saving" you, you're new but it doesn't look that bad.

Comment: i've tried dude and failed. this forum is meant for helping each other out. I've added the html snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify in html that is it will be an array of files
and then call the foreach in your php, basically the post will be an array.

My example is not using PDO or adapted to your example but it is working in uploading multiple files.

PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
    $errors= array();
    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
        if($file_size > 2097152){
            $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }       
        $query="INSERT into upload_data (`USER_ID`,`FILE_NAME`,`FILE_SIZE`,`FILE_TYPE`) VALUES('$user_id','$file_name','$file_size','$file_type'); ";
        $desired_dir="user_data";
        if(empty($errors)==true){
            if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
            }
            if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"user_data/".$file_name);
            }else{                                  //rename the file if another one exist
                $new_dir="user_data/".$file_name.time();
                 rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
            }
            mysql_query($query);            
        }else{
                print_r($errors);
        }
    }
    if(empty($error)){
        echo "Success";
    }
}
?>
```

HTML

```
<form action="yourphpfile.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="" />
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: glad to be of help.

Comment: being the correct way,  you must also consider as stated by @dtz that it's not using PDO,  so I recommend to look for the use of PDO, Prepared Statements, in order to avoid SQL injections.